Replacing font face in .sty file of `newspaper`
I'm trying to modify the .sty file of newspaper package to create newsletters for my bonsai club. I'd like to replace the gothic default font with [demibold,condensed]cabin which is the best replacement for Avenir Next Condensed used in our logo.
I'm not 100% sure of what I'm doing, and I couldn't find any piece of documentation helping me to make progress. I would be grateful if you could point out any error I'm making or better ways of doing what I'm trying to do.
Please find below what I've tried so far:

I had a look into the newspaper.sty file and I've seen the following:
%% The following line "imports" the 'yfont' package with the gothic fonts.
% \RequirePackage{yfonts}  % used for the paper title font
%% Since a font similar to Avenir Next Condensed used in our logo 
%% is defined in 'cabin' with parameters 'semibold' and 'condensed'
%% I added:
% \RequirePackage[semibold, condensed]{cabin}


Later on, I've found the definition for the page title style:
% %define font for page title
% \DeclareFontFamily{LYG}{bigygoth}{}
% \DeclareFontShape{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.0]ygoth}{}
%% Which I just commented out following the advices in the comments.


Later on, I see the \maketitle command redeclared and as part of it:
% ...
% {\textgoth{\huge\usefont{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n} \@papername}}\hfill% 
%% which, following advices, I replaced with:
{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge \@papername}\hfill%



Unexpectedly, I've got something that resembles what I was trying to achieve! I noticed however that the font should be twice as big to fill the header space. I believe this was achieved with the \DeclareFontShape{...} that I commented out: I tried to mess with the command a little but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I'm providing a modified version of newsletter.sty and mwe.tex below. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!
mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{newsprint}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{TWRed}{RGB}{207, 46, 54}

\SetPaperName{The \textcolor{TWRed}{TW}ickenham \textcolor{TWRed}{TW}ig} 
\SetHeaderName{The quick brown fox:} 
\SetPaperLocation{} 
\SetPaperSlogan{\includegraphics[width=1.0in]{logo.jpg}} 
\SetPaperPrice{}

\date{December 2024}
\currentvolume{5}
\currentissue{22}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\byline{\sc\Large Geek Designs New \LaTeX{} Package}{Matthew Allen}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\closearticle

\end{document}

newsprint.sty
%%% Modified version of newsprint by Stefano Bragaglia 
%%% to create the newsletter of the TWickenham bonsai club 
%%% with help from the community on tex.stackexchange.com
%%%
%%% Below the attribution of the original package:
%%% 
%%% Matthew Allen
%%% January 14, 2007
%%%
%%% This package provides a newspaper style heading
%%% for the standard Article class.  The default plain
%%% page style is redefined to accomodate headings 
%%% at the top of all subsequent pages.
%%%
%%% a good idea to use with this package is
%%% the multicols package and the picinpar package
%%%

%*******    Identification   *****
\ProvidesPackage{newspaper}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%*******    Declaration of options *****

% no options at this time

%*******    Execution of options   *****

%******     Package Loading   *****
% \RequirePackage{yfonts}  % used for the paper title font
\RequirePackage[semibold,condensed]{cabin}  % used for the paper title font
                                            % similar to Avenir Next Condensed
                                            % used in the club logo

%******     main code *****

%define font for page title
% \DeclareFontFamily{LYG}{bigygoth}{}
% \DeclareFontShape{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.5]ygoth}{}

%%%%%%%%%%% Define Text Dimensions  %%%%%%%

\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}         % article default = -58pt
\setlength\headheight{0pt}          % article default = 12pt
\setlength\headsep{34pt}            % article default = 25pt
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}    % article default = 121pt
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}         % article default = 418pt
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}        % article default = 296pt
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}

%%%% counters for volume and number %%%%

\newcounter{volume}
\newcommand\currentvolume[1]{\setcounter{volume}{#1}}
\newcounter{issue}
\newcommand\currentissue[1]{\setcounter{issue}{#1}}

%%%% set internal variables %%%%

\def\@papername{Committee Times}
\def\@headername{Committee Times:}   % because of the yfonts you may need both papername and headername
\def\@paperlocation{Washington DC}
\def\@paperslogan{``All the News I Feel Like Printing.''}
\def\@paperprice{Zero Dollars}

\newcommand\SetPaperName[1]{%
    \def\@papername{#1}}
\newcommand\SetHeaderName[1]{%
    \def\@headername{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperLocation[1]{%
    \def\@paperlocation{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperSlogan[1]{%
    \def\@paperslogan{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperPrice[1]{%
    \def\@paperprice{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%% Redefine \maketitle     %%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\begin{center}\small \@paperslogan\end{center}}}}}\hfill%
% {\textgoth{\huge\usefont{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n} \@papername}}\hfill%
{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge \@papername}\hfill%
\raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@paperlocation}}\\
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
}

%%%%%%%   redefine plain page style  %%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
        \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}%                   % empty recto footer
        \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot                     % empty verso footer
        \renewcommand\@evenhead
            {\parbox{\textwidth}{\vspace*{4pt}
            {\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}}\hfill\normalfont\textbf{\@headername}\quad\MakeUppercase{\it\@date}\hfill\textrm{\thepage}\\
            \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
            \vspace*{12pt}}}%
        \let\@oddhead\@evenhead}
        

%%%%%%%%%%%  Headline (with byline) command  %%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\headline[1]{\begin{center} #1\\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
\newcommand\byline[2]{\begin{center} #1 \\%
            {\footnotesize\bf By \MakeUppercase{#2}} \\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
\newcommand\closearticle{{\begin{center}\rule[6pt]{\hsize}{1pt}\vspace*{-16pt}
            \rule{\hsize}{0.5pt}\end{center}}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End of Package   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


We need a minimal example to play with. Anyway, your \DeclareFontShape command makes no sense at all and you certainly need to remove \textgoth.

In addition to what @egreg said, DejaVuSansCondensed.sty doesn't affect \normalfont. It only alters \sfdefault, whereas \normalfont uses, by default, \rmdefault. If you have loaded the package with \RequirePackage{DejaVuSansCondensed}, just use \sffamily or \textsf{} for the title. But note this will also change any other usage of sans text in your newsletter.

Many thanks for the suggestions. I've included them in my question, and more importantly, I added an MWE. I realised that the font is too small even though its \Huge, so I updated my question.

off-topic: don't use times; don't use two-letter font switches in LaTeX (except possibly \em which isn't a font-switch per se) e.g. \sc should be \scshape or \textsc{}.

if this package uses the LPPL, putting a modified version in your question without changing the name is probably illegal, but I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

that's not Cabin. it's using an helvetica clone.

Edit: Italics should work fine now. The switch to Cabin is now confined to uses of \titlefont or \texttitle{} which provide a font switch and text font command in the usual way. So \textsf{}, for example, will give Computer Modern Sans. See below for details


Possibly something along these lines,
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{newsprint.sty}
%%% insert your licence statement here and declare the package as a derivative,
%%% if applicable (but good practice even if not required)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% original licence statement:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Matthew Allen
%%% January 14, 2007
%%%
%%% This package provides a newspaper style heading
%%% for the standard Article class.  The default plain
%%% page style is redefined to accomodate headings
%%% at the top of all subsequent pages.
%%%
%%% a good idea to use with this package is
%%% the multicols package and the picinpar package
%%%
%%% Modified by Stefano Bragaglia to create
%%% the newsletter of the TWickenham bonsai club
%%% with help from the community on tex.stackexchange.com
%%%

%*******    Identification   *****
\ProvidesPackage{newsprint}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%*******    Declaration of options *****

% no options at this time

%*******    Execution of options   *****

%******     Package Loading   *****
% \RequirePackage[semibold,condensed]{cabin}  % used for the paper title font
% similar to Avenir Next Condensed
% used in the club logo

%******     main code *****

%define font for page title
% \DeclareFontFamily{LYG}{bigygoth}{}
% \DeclareFontShape{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.5]ygoth}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand \titlefont{%
  \not@math@alphabet\titlefont\relax
  \fontfamily{Cabin-TLF}\fontseries{sbc}\upshape
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand \texttitle{\titlefont}

%%%%%%%%%%% Define Text Dimensions  %%%%%%%

\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}         % article default = -58pt
\setlength\headheight{0pt}          % article default = 12pt
\setlength\headsep{34pt}            % article default = 25pt
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}    % article default = 121pt
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}         % article default = 418pt
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}        % article default = 296pt
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}

%%%% counters for volume and number %%%%

\newcounter{volume}
\newcommand\currentvolume[1]{\setcounter{volume}{#1}}
\newcounter{issue}
\newcommand\currentissue[1]{\setcounter{issue}{#1}}

%%%% set internal variables %%%%

\def\@papername{Committee Times}
\def\@headername{Committee Times:}   % because of the yfonts you may need both papername and headername
\def\@paperlocation{Washington DC}
\def\@paperslogan{``All the News I Feel Like Printing.''}
\def\@paperprice{Zero Dollars}

\newcommand\SetPaperName[1]{%
\def\@papername{#1}}
\newcommand\SetHeaderName[1]{%
\def\@headername{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperLocation[1]{%
\def\@paperlocation{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperSlogan[1]{%
\def\@paperslogan{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperPrice[1]{%
\def\@paperprice{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%% Redefine \maketitle     %%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-40pt}
  \begin{center}
    {\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\begin{center}\small \@paperslogan\end{center}}}}}\hfill
    {\titlefont\bfseries\fontsize{40pt}{10pt}\selectfont\@papername}\hfill
    \raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@paperlocation}}\\
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
    {\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill \MakeUppercase{\small\itshape\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
    \rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
  \end{center}
  \pagestyle{plain}%
}

%%%%%%%   redefine plain page style  %%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}%                   % empty recto footer
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot                     % empty verso footer
  \renewcommand\@evenhead
  {\parbox{\textwidth}{\vspace*{4pt}
      {\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}}\hfill\normalfont\textbf{\@headername}\quad\MakeUppercase{\itshape\@date}\hfill\textrm{\thepage}\\
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
  \vspace*{12pt}}}%
\let\@oddhead\@evenhead}


%%%%%%%%%%%  Headline (with byline) command  %%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\headline[1]{\begin{center} #1\\ %
\rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
\newcommand\byline[2]{\begin{center} #1 \\%
    {\footnotesize\bfseries By \MakeUppercase{#2}} \\ %
\rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
\newcommand\closearticle{{\begin{center}\rule[6pt]{\hsize}{1pt}\vspace*{-16pt}
\rule{\hsize}{0.5pt}\end{center}}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End of Package   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newsprint}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{TWRed}{RGB}{207, 46, 54}

\SetPaperName{The \textcolor{TWRed}{TW}ickenham \textcolor{TWRed}{TW}ig}
\SetHeaderName{The quick brown fox:}
\SetPaperLocation{}
\SetPaperSlogan{\includegraphics[width=1.0in]{logo.jpg}}
\SetPaperPrice{}

\date{December 2024}
\currentvolume{5}
\currentissue{22}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\byline{\scshape\Large Geek Designs New \LaTeX{} Package}{Matthew Allen}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

% \textit{Italics \textsc{small-caps} \textbf{bold}}

% \texttitle{title font} ordinary \textit{italics}
\closearticle
\end{document}

Explanation of edit:
There is a line in cabin.sty which looks intentional but constitutes a bug, IMHO, which somebody should report to the author.
If postscript type1 fonts are used, the following code is executed:
  \ifcabin@condensed
    \def\bfseries@sf{bc}
    \ifcabin@semibold\def\bfseries@sf{sbc}\fi
    \def\mdseries@sf{c}
    \ifcabin@medium\def\mdseries@sf{mediumcondensed}\fi
    \def\seriesdefault{\mdseries@sf}
  ...

So if you use the condensed option:

\bfseries@sf is changed from bx (or b) to bc or sbc, which is quite reasonable;
\mdseries@sf is changed from m to c or mediumcondensed, at least the first of which is reasonable, though I would not recommend the second;
\seriesdefault is changed from m to c, which is not at all reasonable, IMHO, since this changes the series default for all fonts - not just Cabin or sans, but also serif, typewriter and the rest.

What then happens is that font switches in the body of the document, which use TG Termes rather than Cabin, consistently fail. They fail because an attempt to change to italics, say, tries to find a condensed italic. Failing to do so, LaTeX falls back on condensed upright. That doesn't really exist either, but a non-condensed upright is used. This then gets substituted for all the other non-existent fonts. This happens because of the way LaTeX does font substitution, which is somewhat complicated. But the upshot is that you mostly get upright regardless of what shape you ask for.
What the edit does is avoid loading cabin at all and instead just load the .fd file directly to define a special font for titling.
If you also wanted to switch sans to condensed Cabin, you could restore the loading of the cabin package and add
\def\seriesdefault{m}

after loading the package. This will restore the default series and should hopefully more-or-less work as expected.
A font package which provides a complete font configuration has some justification for redefining \seriesdefault, but that's not the case here and the change is neither desirable nor necessary, IMHO.
Edit
[In response to request in comments for a lighter font.]
If I change \fontseries{sbc} to \fontseries{c} in the definition of \titlefont and remove \bfseries from the definition of \maketitle, then I get the regular-weight condensed rather than the semi-bold:


Brilliant, thanks! Also for the good comments and advices above.

By the way, it seems I cannot get italic text to work with \usepackage{tgtermes} is it normal?

@StefanoBragaglia no, that is not normal. hang on ...

@StefanoBragaglia please see edit above. I'd encourage you to report the issue to cabin's author.

Thanks so much: I would never got to the end of it by myself! I'll try to report the issue to Cabin's maintainer but indeed it's a problematic font: if you see the logo in my picture the font is quite light. I've tried to change \fontseries{sbc} to \fontseries{slc} or \fontseries{lc} but the font doesn't change... I've considered switching to QTHelvetCnd or QTHelvetCnd-Light from QualiType but couldn't do the change myself... I think I'm entering a rabbit hole...

Same with "roboto condensed"

@StefanoBragaglia try c for condensed. I don't think the font has lc. the .fd files use an additional layer of aliases, which further complicates figuring out what's going on. It doesn't surprise me if other fonts show the same problem as there are a number of font packages by the same author.

Thanks again, I’ve tried with just “c” but haven’t seen any difference visually… which is weird because the \normalfont seen at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/cabincondensed/ is much thinner! That’s why I started to consider other condensed font from such site.

@StefanoBragaglia did you remove \bfseries from the definition of \maketitle? see edit above

Thank you very much, you are a legend!
Just for the sake of discussion, please find below an excerpt of the newspaper package that explains why the times package was picked:

As a general rule, Times-Roman (or Times New Roman as its variants are sometimes called) is a terrible font and should always be avoided. There is, how- ever, one exception to the rule: when setting columns of text. The Times New Roman typeface was developed in 1931 for The Times of London.


And again:

The letters are more narrow than other typefaces and the ascenders and descenders are smaller. This makes it ideal for newspapers, that always strive to squeeze more words onto a single page in order to reduce production costs. Its economic advatage has made it popular with book publishers in the United States.


@StefanoBragaglia yes, I know the history. but the point is that times is outdated. if you want to use TNR or Times or whatever, pick one of the newer implementations. TeX Gyre Termes is a newer times clone, but there are other similar options. (note that you are getting a clone anyway. the question is just which clone you get. times provides a rather old, URW clone on most machines. it was a reasonable choice at the time, but not so much now. tgtermes, one of the newer times-alike packages, stix ... they will all provide a similar font face, but with better results.

Thanks for the explanation. I’m more than fine with Gyre Termes. Just wanted to explain why Times was there to start with…
